# Create and merge multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, merge

I have multiple files. Each corresponding to the data of a city having an ID and "VOLUME" column.
I am trying to create dataframes from csv files and after treatments i would like to merge these dataframes by "ID" with all "VOLUME" columns like this : VOLUME_{CITY} with {CITY} corresponding to the name of the city.

So far i did this :

```
data_dir_file = 'Data'

cities = ['NY','Chicago','Boston','Toronto']

dfs = []
for city in cities: 
    file_name = f'Data_2010_{city}.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{data_dir_file}\{file_name}',sep=';')
    df = df[['ID','VOLUME']].drop_duplicates()
    dfs.append(df)
df_concat = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df_concat)
```

So this concatenates each dataframe but how can i merge them by "ID" instead of doing a concatenation ?

Each dataframe looks like this

[image]

What i want is something like this :

[image]

Comment: please show examples of your pre-merged input tables and what you expect the post-output merged table to be

Comment: did you try `DataFrame.merge`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` to merge your data by the ID (also change the name of column "VOLUME", otherwise they'll be renamed as VOLUME_x, VOLUME_y losing information about the city)

```
data_dir_file = 'Data'

cities = ['NY','Chicago','Boston','Toronto']

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for city in cities: 
    file_name = f'Data_2010_{city}.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{data_dir_file}\{file_name}',sep=';')
    df = df[['ID','VOLUME']].drop_duplicates()
    df.columns = ['ID','VOLUME_'+city]
    if len(dfs) == 0:
        dfs = df
    else:
        dfs = dfs.merge(df, on= 'ID', outer=True)
```

Comment: got this error : pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 30 fields in line 270107, saw 31